# Does android with in app purchase have to be listed as free

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am developing an android app and want to offer a trial period, with purchase  after trial. If I do this do I then list it a free app?, how do potential buyers thinking it is free for a limited time know they will have to purchase after say 30 days?

I have googled various options for pricing and listing of Google play console, but it is not clear, it seems that once a app listed as free it cannot be converted to a priced app, but if I list it as free with in app purchase, is that ok? Thanks.